# Resolving conflicts between static and dynamic routes using Flask

Tags: python, flask

Let us say I create a blog, it has three static routes which are set up as usual. If none of the static routes match I want my method post_page() to return the answer by looking up the blog post in the database:

```
/                  → def index_page(): return "Index page"
/about             → def index_page(): return "About page"
/contact           → def index_page(): return "Contact page"
/<somethingelse>   → def post_page(): return get_content(somethingelse)
```

Some example URLs would be:

```
http://localhost/                                 → show the index page
http://localhost/about                            → show the about page
http://localhost/contact                          → show the contact page
http://localhost/the-largest-known-prime-number   → shows my log about the largest known prime number, it is fetched from the database.
http://localhost/my-cat                           → shows my log about my cat
http://localhost/my-dog                           → shows my log about my dog
```

What is the best way to do this using Flask? If it is possible I still want to be able to use `url_for('about')` to lookup the URLs of my static routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply define your routes with the static ones first, and it will work. The router will look for the best match and return it.

```
-> request comes in with /contact
|  /contact is in the routes
<- return call to contact function

-> request comes in with /foo-bar
|  /foo-bar matches the "postPage" route's regexp
<- return call to `postPage` function
```

Side note: see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ about your function names (camel case is evil in Python).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll update the function names. I was in Java-mode when I wrote them. ;-)

Comment: I don't have to define my static routes first, the routing seems to takes the most specific match. Your answer could be a bit clearer, if you clearly stated that the route defenition order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Kent - ah, I wasn't aware of that (I haven't used Flask for more than a year, though I am about to again). I thought it would simply find the first match in the set (even though I said "best match", I really was thinking "first match"). I will correct it (as well as add link to the docs) when I get a few more minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use 1 view for both static and dynamic. using your example, it will be something like

```
static_page_list = ['about','contact']

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<static_page>')
def hello(static_page=None):
    if static_page not in static_page_list:
        return get_content(somethingelse)
    else
        static_page_html = static_page + ".html"
        return render_template(static_page_html)
```

Now you can visit:

/

/about

/contact

/anything_else

Comment: The solution by orokusaki works well. I wanted the static URL to call its function and dynamic ones to call theirs. If I define things like he suggested it works as I want it. Your solution would not make `url_for('.....')` work, right?